# Adding tabs to an existing toolbar in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, toolbar

I have an existing toolbar and would like to add tabs to it that would flip between two panels that use a card layout.  What would be my best option and are there any examples of doing so?

- Is it possible to add the tabs to my existing toolbar?  Changing the xtype on my existing buttons didn't provide me with the tabs I was hoping to see.
- Create a tab panel which would contain my two cards, mapping each tab to its panel.  With this option, can I add additional buttons and menus to the tab panel?

Here's a sample of my existing toolbar code, can message_button and attachments_button simply have an xtype of tab and then somehow emulate the tab functionality?

```
Ext.define('MyArchive.Toolbar', {                                                                                                                                                 
  alias: 'myarchive.toolbar',                                                                                                                                                     
  extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',                                                                                                                                                  
  dock: 'top',                                                                                                                                                                    
  width: '100%',                                                                                                                                                                  
  items: [
    // Pretty straight forward buttons with a listener, nothing fancy
    messages_button,                                                                                                                                                                  
    attachments_button,                                                                                                                                         
    '->',                                                                                                                                                                         
    { xtype: 'button', id: 'forward-button', text: 'Forward' },                                                                                                                    
    '-',                                                                                                                                                                          
    { xtype: 'button', id: 'recover-button', text: 'Recover' },                                                                                                                    
    '-',                                                                                                                                                                          
   {                                                                                                                                                                              
     text: 'Download',                                                                                                                                                            
     menu: {                                                                                                                                                                      
       xtype: 'menu',                                                                                                                                                             
       id: 'download-menu',                                                                                                                                                       
       items: [                                                                                                                                                                   
         {xtype: 'menuitem', id: 'download-original', text: 'Original', iconCls: 'download-icon'},                                                                                
         {xtype: 'menuitem', id: 'download-pdf', text: 'PDF', iconCls: 'pdf-icon'}                                                                                                
       ]                                                                                                                                                                          
     }                                                                                                                                                                            
   }                                                                                                                                                                              
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add the tabs to my existing toolbar? Changing the
>   xtype on my existing buttons didn't provide me with the tabs I was
>   hoping to see.

I've tried it. But no luck.

> Create a tab panel which would contain my two cards, mapping each tab
>   to its panel. With this option, can I add additional buttons and menus
>   to the tab panel?

It is possible. But result looks ugly (you can decorate it with CSS).
Use `tabpanel.tabBar.add()` to add buttons and menus ([Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/3xJUN/)):

```
tabpanel.tabBar.add({
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'hallo, I\'m a button'
});
tabpanel.tabBar.add({
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: 'Download',
    menu: {
        xtype: 'menu',
        id: 'download-menu',
        // ans so on ...
```